# Animate <div> to unknown height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, smoothing

Situation:
I have an index page which loads pages into it with ajax as such:

```
$("#ajax2").load("contact.php");
```

I do so with all my pages, but it changes the size real choppy and I want to animate this.

Important stuff from my index page:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li id="current"><a href="#" id="home" onclick="pages('home');">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="contact" onclick="pages('contact');">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

My javascript function:

```
var pages = function(id) {
switch(id) {
    case 'home':
        $("#ajax2").load("home.php");
        break;
    case 'contact':
        $("#ajax2").load("contact.php");
        break;
}
};
```

Does anyone can point me in the direction on what I need to do so my div "ajax2" changes the size real smooth?

I would have used

```
$("#ajax2").animate({ height: '60px' }, 'easeInOutCubic', function(){
});
```

except I don't know the height of the contact/home/any page.

Solved

Comment: See one of my older my websites at http://yankele.co.il where I implemented this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#ajax2")
  .css({
    display:'none'
  })
  .load('home.php', function () {
    var height;
    height = $(this).height();
    $(this)
      .css({
        height :0,
        display:'block'
      })
      .animate({
        height:height
      }, 1000, 'linear', function () {
      });
  });
```

Comment: Hi, my console show the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'easeInOutCubic' I tried to fix this but I only made it worse.

Comment: If you want to use easeInOutCubic, download jquery.easing.1.3.js from [jQuey Easing Plugin](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/) and load to your html. Then rewrite 'linear' to $.easing.easeInOutCubic.

Comment: If I do that the console shows: Uncaught TypeError: Property 'function (x, t, b, c, d) {

  if ((t/=d/2) < 1) return c/2*t*t*t + b;

  return c/2*((t-=2)*t*t + 2) + b;

 }' of object #<Object> is not a function

Comment: Try to rewrite `'linear'` to `'easeOutExpo'`. The way of specifying the easing argument depends on jQuery version. I guess..

Answer (score 0):

> > except I don't know the height of the contact/home/any page.

Find the height using height function

```
var h = $("#ajax2").height();

$("#ajax2").animate({ height: h }, 'easeInOutCubic', function(){
});
```

Comment: This solution does not apply, I'll edit the question with a live example.